# Capture HTTP Request & Response without writing boiler plate code in every class

Tags: http, request, jboss, response, weblogic14c

I am looking out for possible Java-based solutions to capture all the requests and responses.

I am thinking of a simple java agent to attach to the server to log the requests and responses.

The main intention of this exercise is to improve the application's health. Also not interested in proprietary tools like App dynamics etc.,

Comment: A servlet filter can be a solution as mentioned by ehsavoie.
You can also extend built-in WebLogic access logs to meet your needs. See this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/web_server.htm#CNFGD204)for details.
You can also use these debug flags to get informations about HTTP exchanges : 
`-Dweblogic.debug.DebugHttp=true -Dweblogic.debug.DebugHttpLogging=true`

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. We explored this option. But the challenge here is we need to read the log files and store these requests on our tables.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use servlet filters for this ? Also you have to consider the huge performance impact.
Another solution is to have support of microprofile metrics in your application server.